# SharePoint List Calendar view (Month and Week) Item sotring by name

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I'm using SharePoint List to show some items in calendar view.
However, the sorting order of the items on each day keeps changing. Default setting may have been modified time.
I want to show the list always sorted by name. How can I achieve this?

What I tried so far

- List Settings > View > Weekly > Sort option : This doesn't work. (The column I selected as a sorting column is also selected in Display columns.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a Sort for this calendar view.
Please go to List Settings->Views->click your calendar view. Sort the columns according to the item name.
[image]